# Trying to change source of an image in a list

Tags: android, android-listview, imageview, onclicklistener, listviewitem

i have a listview in which each list item contains an ImageView. Now in my adapter class i set a click listener on the ImageView which changes the image resource. I am using simple code and it works but i have unique problem that if i click on any image it changes but also the image of the subsequent 6th list item changes. this a very unique problem i am facing and i dont understand what is causing it.

My click listener in my adapter class:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Movie> movieItems;
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.movieItems = movieItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return movieItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return movieItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    final ImageView favIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.favIcon);
    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView rating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
    TextView location = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.location);

    // getting movie data for the row
    Movie m = movieItems.get(position);

    // thumbnail image
    thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);

    // title
    title.setText(m.getTitle());

    // rating
    rating.setText("Rating: " + String.valueOf(m.getRating()));

    // location
    location.setText("Location:" + String.valueOf(m.getLocation()));

    favIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((ImageView)v).setImageResource(R.drawable.batdroid);
        }
    });


    return convertView;
}

}
```

Comment: can you post the rest of your adapter code please?

Comment: Ok ,so when you click you change the image of that selected row but also the last row's image changes ? or just the 6th?

Comment: the subsequent 6th. for example if i click 1st then 7th also changes,if i click 2nd then 8th also changes etc.

Comment: also the reverse is happening. if i select 8th, then 2nd will also change

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessin' it's a recycle view issue . You should use the View Holder pattern , check [this](http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/) for a wider view.

Anyway you should try something like this :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.img= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = convertView.getTag();
    }



// set for each image in yourlist
        holder.img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((ImageView) v).setImageResource(R.drawable.batdroid);
            }
        });


    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView img;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help man but i tried and its still not fixed. do u think by any chance its an emulator issue cus i'm working on an emulator?

Comment: I don't think so , but you should try testing it on your phone , or any phone